# Combining multiple arrays in a timetable

Tags: php

I need a solution how to find all possible combinations of a schedule. There are courses on given dates that can vary by length. There is a given number of weeks. I need to find a solution to all possible combinations including all courses, with no overlapping.

```
$courses = array ("A", "B", "C", "D");
$duration = array (2, 3, 1, 2); // duration of $courses (in weeks)
$start_dates = array (
  $courses[0] => array (1, 3, 5),
  $courses[1] => array (1, 2, 5, 6),
  $courses[2] => array (3, 4, 5, 9),
  $courses[3] => array (1, 4, 8));
```

I would like to get all the possible combinations, e.g. this:

```
Week | Course 
1    | A
2    | A
3    | C
4    | D
5    | D
6    | B
7    | B
8    | B
9    | -
10   | -
```

Second combination would be e.g. this:

```
Week | Course 
1    | A
2    | A
3    | -
4    | C
5    | B
6    | B
7    | B
8    | D
9    | D
10   | -
```

The preferred output would be an array with week => course, like this:

```
$combinations = array (
 0 => array (
  1 => $courses[0], 
  2 => $courses[0], 
  3 => $courses[2],
  4 => $courses[3],
  ...
 ),
 1 => array (
  1 => $courses[0], 
  2 => $courses[0], 
  4 => $courses[2],
  5 => $courses[1],
  6 => $courses[1],
  7 => $courses[1],
  ...
 )
);
```

I am really stuck with this problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I hate to post comments like this one but: do you have elaborate the problem? There is some code you can show us to start with? Where do you encounter problems?

Comment: I am just not able to come up with an algorithm. I need just a hint how to do it. Anything I tried takes up too much memory or takes too long. There are 40 weeks and 15 different courses.